# i want to use map like google map and its functonalitties in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Hello I want to use Map(like google map) and its related plugin for free use in jsp. Client want to use map function in my application.
Can any one help me.

Comment: It took just 2 seconds for me to Google on that https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can use leaflet js . i think this is what you want.

Comment: thanxs its helpful for me.